# Boolean 2D array initialization error C++

Tags: c++

This program is suppose to take a `size` amount of pairs of numbers which are coordinates within a 2D boolean array. Every coordinate triggered switches the value to `TRUE`. For some reason I am having errors in the last row as well as the last space in the last row. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main(){
    const int size = 10;
    int *x = new int [size];
    int *y = new int [size];
    bool table[size][size] =  {{false}};
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= size; i++){
        cin >> x[i] >> y[i];
        if(x[i] <= size && y[i] <= size){
            table[x[i]][y[i]] = true;
        } else{
            cout << "invalid input \n";
            i--;
        }
    }


    for(int a = 1; a <= size; a++){
        for(int b= 1; b <= size; b++){
            cout << table[a][b] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you iterate from 1? Should start from 0 in C.

Comment: Yea I understand that, but I cannot use 0s... they're the termination keys. so I worked only with the array starting at 1 and instead of making it `i < size` I did `i <= size`...

Answer (score 3):

Array indices go from 0 to N-1 for an array of size N. You are writing beyond the bounds of the array. Your loops should be something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) { ..... }
```

Comment: Yea I understand that, but I cannot use 0s... they're the termination keys. so I worked only with the array starting at 1 and instead of making it `i < size` I did `i <= size`...

Comment: @GalAppelbaum at the very least, you should avoid looping up to `size`. Although I don't understand how these "termination keys" could work. What is the point of not using a whole row and a whole column of the array?